# iPhone app user identifier

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, ios4

I would like to avoid the hassle of "sign up" and "logging in" to create a profile on the server side for the specific app user. Instead, I thought about identifying the user according to an unique identifier of the phone (like phone num. for example - if that's possible). Have you seen apps that do that? What identifier can I use?

Thanks

Comment: the phone number is private for security reasons. but you can use the id provided by badcat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each iOS device has a unique identifier.

```
NSString *uniqueId = [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];
```

However, each user has possibly more than one iOS device but only a single "user account". It might be a good idea to still do some kind of "sign up", but automatically link the device to that profile afterwards.